# UIControl subclass setHighlighted is not called

Tags: ios, subclass, highlight, uicontrol

I have subclassed UIControl to create my own class. I am trying to override `setHighligheted:` but for some reason it doesn't get called...
I have double checked and none of my subviews have `userInteractionEnabled = NO`. Are there any other methods that I should override?.

Thank you!

Here is some sample code:

```
#import "Booking.h"

@interface BookingCloud : UIControl


// Booking
@property(nonatomic, strong) Booking *booking;

// BackgroundView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *backgroundView;
```

And the implementation

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setUpSubViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setUpSubViews {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BookingCloud" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:backgroundView];
    self.frame = backgroundView.frame;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    if (highlighted) {
          backgroundView.backgroundColor = [[Utils colorWithHexString:[[ConfigurationManager instance] UIConfigValueForKey:@"background_color"]] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8];
    } else {
          backgroundView.backgroundColor = [[Utils colorWithHexString:[[ConfigurationManager instance] UIConfigValueForKey:@"background_color"]] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please post the code that is causing the problem? Will help to have a greater insight into what's happening

Comment: Double check that your method, `setHighlighted:` is spelled correctly in your source. In your question, you spelled it wrong ('e' between the 'h' and the 't'). So, either your question as a simple typo, or if you copy-and-pasted from your source code, it is an indication of your method signature being wrong. Otherwise, yeah, we need to see your code to know for sure.